# Trying to make tessellated vase

Tags: modeling, mesh, 3d-printing

[image]

I made this tessellated vase, but now I want to create an inner body for it but so it connects with the outside, but I don't now how.

Comment: Hi, it's unclear what you mean. Please edit your question and explain it in more detail. Maybe you could share a sketch of what your goal is?

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps it's not the best way, but you can try to duplicate the vase in a new object, then scale down a little to form inner body.

You shouldn't have any connection problems with the vase.

I hope I have helped you.